# Insert data into empty (null) column from another column where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, conditional-statements, insert-into

I need to update column, 'ProvTypeDesc' in my SQL table [LDH_Provider_Crosswalk].  I have created the column and set all the values to null for now.

This needs to get populated from column ProvType_Desc on table [LevelofCareCrosswalk].  The thought process is update ProvTypeDesc from  [LDH_Provider_Crosswalk] t1 with ProvType_Desc from [LevelofCareCrosswalk] t2 where t1.provtype = t2.provtype.  (Both tables have the provtype column with appropriate values that tie to the prov type description.

I am not sure if I should be using an "insert into" or "update" statement in this case.  Maybe there is another statement I should be using?  Anyways, here is what my code looks like, but it doesn't work.  It just appends data from t2 to the bottom of t1.

My attempt at an insert into statement:

```
INSERT INTO [LDH_Provider_Crosswalk] ([ProvTypeDesc])
SELECT t1.ProvType_Desc 
FROM [LevelofCareCrosswalk] t1
JOIN [LevelofCareCrosswalk] t2
ON t1.ProvType = t2.ProvType
```

My attempt at an update statement:

```
UPDATE [LDH_Provider_Crosswalk]
SET t1.[ProvTypeDesc] = t2.ProvType_Desc
FROM [LDH_Provider_Crosswalk] t1 
JOIN [LevelofCareCrosswalk] t2
ON t1.ProvType = t2.ProvType
```

Example data from tables:
[LDH_Provider_Crosswalk] t1 (this table needs the values)
ProvType | ProvTypeDesc
11    |     NULL
43    |     NULL
37    |     NULL

Example data from tables:
[LevelofCareCrosswalk] t2 (this table contains the values)
ProvType | ProvTypeDesc
11    |    Crisis Receiving Center
43    |    Therapeutic Foster Care
37    |    Center Based Respite

Did a little more research.  It looks like update statement is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  I just needed to remove the alias from the set statement.

```
UPDATE [LDH_Provider_Crosswalk]
SET [ProvTypeDesc] = t2.ProvType_Desc
FROM [LDH_Provider_Crosswalk] t1 
JOIN [LevelofCareCrosswalk] t2
ON t1.ProvType = t2.ProvType
```